# How to specify styles for the table in a PDF file

Tags: java

I can able to create a PDF by itext,but I'm in trouble now.I want to merge the cells in the table and specify the table location.But I can only achieve one function.
code:

```
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
        import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
        import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
        import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
        import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
        import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
        import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
        import com.sinosoft.lis.f1print.pdf.EPdfPTable;
        import com.sinosoft.lis.f1print.pdf.PdfPubFun;
```

//demo

```
        public class ItextHelloword {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                //create a pdf
                tableOutput2("f:/itext-demo222.pdf"); 
            }
```

//method

```
        public static void tableOutput2(String pdfFilePath) throws Exception {
                Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                PdfContentByte mPdfContentByte = null;
                try
                {
                    PdfWriter writer = null;
                    BaseFont mBaseFont = null;
                    try
                    {
                        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdfFilePath));
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
                    {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    document.open();
                    mPdfContentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
                    try
                    {
                        mBaseFont = BaseFont.createFont("STSong-Light", "UniGB-UCS2-H", BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                catch (DocumentException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   
                EPdfPTable table = new EPdfPTable(3);
                table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                table.setWidthPercentage(100);
                table.addCell("C");
                table.addCell("D");
                table.addCell("E");
                table.addCell(2,"A");
                table.addCell("B");
                table.addCell("C");
                table.addCell("D");
                table.addCell("E");
                table.addCell("C");
                table.addCell("D");
                table.addCell("E");
                document.add(table);
```

//specify the table location

```
                PdfPubFun.dealTable(document, table, 10, 70, 500, mPdfContentByte);
               document.close();
               System.out.println("Finished!");
            }
        }
```

Please give me a hand!Thanks!

Edit:

[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxp8C.png)

This is my PDF file.I want to create a table such as table 1 and the location such as table 2.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more, don't understand the problem clearly

Comment: I just uploaded a photo.Please...

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt can you help me?